# How to deploy new version of .NET component to allow easy rollback to prior version

Tags: .net, interop

What is the best way to deploy a new version of a .NET component and to allow easy rollback to a prior version?

The .NET DLL is being used by a VB6 app.  What would be the best way to quickly revert to the prior version of the DLL if a problem occurred with the new DLL?

Comment: You got good answers, what else do you need?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need more details to make this work, but you might consider writing a wrapper that the VB6 code calls directly.

In the wrapper, you can use a combination of configuration files and AppDomains to load whatever .NET assemblies you wish using whatever rules you wish.  (You could load and unload assemblies on the fly, for instance.)

Comment: Are you saying I would need to have different file and assembly names for the two different versions?

Comment: Not necessarily.  But you would have to differentiate between them somehow.  Having different versions in different folders would be sufficient.